# Adobe Edge generated video with overlay, play on ios without full screen

Tags: javascript, css, svg, adobe-edge, svg-animate

I have an animation made in Adobe Edge, featuring an animated body with an overlay of a face, pulled via an URL parameter.

It works fine on web. However, on IOS a video can only be played full screen - and then the image overlay obviously doesn't show.

Does anyone know a solution of how I could make this work on IOS? Either some way to convert the video+overlay to a merged video, svg animation or something else? Or just play the video without fullscreen - but I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS mobile devices videos played in Safari go full screen with no other elements available. There is no way to stop this behaviour in Safari. Videos can be made to play inline within a native app, but not Safari unfortunately.

on iOS tablet devices, videos can be played inline within Safari.

However,you mentioned that you've created the animation in Adobe Edge Animate? I'd be tempted to publish your animation as a web animation and use that where your video would be.